# Add text to the end of PDF files

Tags: pdf, edit, bulk

**Hello**, is there a way to bulk add graphics to PDFs files. Ex. I have 4000 PDFs. In the end of each PDFs file i need to add identical graphic. Is there a possibility to do this ALL at once or i have to do it manually.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

iText: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext

- If you using .NET then http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/
- JAVA: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

good luck